# Who is setting my LS_COLORS?

Tags: terminal, ls, colors

I'm using the `bash` shell, and want to change some of my `ls` listing colors; I've noticed that [this can be controlled using the `LS_COLORS` environment variable](https://linuxhint.com/ls_colors_bash/), which encodes terminal colors for various file and directory types and states.

Now, I *have* `LS_COLORS` set in my environment, but I don't remember / don't know who exactly sets it! I can't find any `export LS_COLORS` or even a mention of `LS_COLORS` in my `.bashrc`, `.bash_login`, etc.

So where is it set?

Note: I'm using a Debian-based distribution

Answer (score 6):

The `LS_COLORS` variable is likely set using the GNU [`dircolors` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/dircolors-invocation.html) - so the environment variable name is not used directly. A typical `.bashrc` fragment you would find on Debian-like systems would be:

```
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
fi
```

So, here's what you want to do:

- If `~/.dircolors` doesn't exist, create it using `dircolors -p > ~/.dircolors`
- Edit `~/.dircolors` using your favorite text editor
- Here's [another man-like page](https://alvinalexander.com/unix/man/man5/dir_colors.5.shtml) explaining how to edit a `dircolors` database rather than the LS_COLORS variable

Now, whenever you start a new shell, you should get the colors you wanted.